# Знаки = и == и ошибки с ними

Tags: python-3.6

[image: сама программа]

На что он ругается? Меняю на ==, всё равно ругается на синтаксис, но в месте с " i == i + 1:". Знаю, что можно написать "i+=i", но он будет выдавать такую же ошибку.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: проблема не в `=`, а в том, что неправильно `for` используется. посмотри примеры его использования, [например тут](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из [описания](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop):

> Обычно `for` используется, когда нужно повторить блок кода определенное количество раз. В Python `for` используется для обхода коллекции.

В данном коде неверное использование `for`.

В качестве альтернативы условию, можно воспользоваться `range`

```
for i in range(1,num+1):
    factor *= i
```

Либо использовать `while`

```
i = 1
while i <= num:
    factor *= i
    i += 1
```